# Convert function / method to string?

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe

i have got the following forecast:

[image]

but i am not able to save as "functional" dataframe. I would like to rename the columns and then plot it.
But nothing does not work.
The whole looks like a one "unit", not a normal dataframe.

I have tried to do something to change it, but without any result.

```
df18.columns = [''] * len(df18.columns)
df18.columns = ['A', 'B']
df18.iloc[0]
```

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'columns'

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'iloc'

```
df18 = df18[:-1]
```

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

---

How i can convert a function to float64? Or to anything that i can work with?

Comment: rename it before you plot it, `prediction.columns = ['A','B']` then `predictions.plot`

Comment: Thank you! What a fail from my side.